# Bounding a summation by an integral

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

In progression of another question, my lecturer states $$\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} \le \int^\infty_N \frac{1}{x^2}\, {\rm d}x.$$

However we have not covered bounding summations by integrals yet so I was wondering if someone could explain the choice of the function to integrate and why the bottom limit is $N$, rather than $N+1$ for example. Is this simply to ensure the integral is definitely greater?

Comment: The $N$ is required. To see this, graph the summation as rectangles starting at $k=N+1$, with the rectangle at $N+1$ extending towards $N$. Then to bound the function we need the integral to start from $N$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at the area under the curve for $1/k^2$ and the sum approximation it will become obvious why this equation makes sense:

[image]

The sum $\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ are the bars and $\int_N^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\mathrm{dx}$ is the area under the line.

The sum has to start 1 unit later, otherwise you would get this:
[image]

which actually shows that the sum starting at N will bound the integral from above.

You can combine these observations to form the equation:
$$ \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} \le \int_{N}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \mathrm{dx} \le \sum_{k=N}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} $$

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\dfrac1{x^2}$ is a decreasing function on (a,b), where $a>0$. Hence, on $(a,b)$, we have
$$\dfrac1{b^2} \leq \dfrac1{x^2} \leq \dfrac1{a^2}$$
Hence, on a unit interval $(m-1,m)$, we have
$$\dfrac1{m^2} \leq \dfrac1{x^2}$$
We hence have
$$\sum_{m=N+1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{m^2} \leq \int_N^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{x^2}$$