# The series $\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} p^{-\frac{7}{6}}$ lies in which of the following intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

The series $\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} p^{-\frac{7}{6}}$ lies in which of the following intervals?

(a) $[1,2]$

(b) $[6,7]$

(c) $[3,4]$

(d) $[5,6]$

I only know that the series converges by $p$-test since $\frac{7}{6} >1$. I don't know how to work further on it. Can please someone explain?

Comment: What about $\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{-7/6} $?

Comment: That's $\zeta(7/6)$ and a first approximation to $\zeta(1+s)$ is 1/s.

Comment: Do you know the integral bound? See here for an example : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282807/bounding-a-summation-by-an-integral

Comment: @TeresaLisbon No, but i will check it out now. Thanks!

Comment: $$
\int_1^\infty x^{-7/6} \,dx \le \sum_{p=1}^\infty p^{-7/6} \le 1 + \int_2^\infty x^{-7/6} \, dx 
$$

Comment: @s1mple Thanks. Once you've done that,see how it is used below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \sum_{p=1}^\infty p^{-7/6} = \sum_{p=1}^\infty \int_p^{p+1} p^{-7/6} \,dx \\[8pt]
\ge {} & \sum_{p=1}^\infty \int_p^{p+1} x^{-7/6}\,dx = \int_1^\infty x^{-7/6}\,dx = 6.
\end{align}
And then in the opposite direction:
\begin{align}
& \sum_{p=1}^\infty p^{-7/6} = 1 + \sum_{p=2}^\infty p^{-7/6} = 1 + \sum_{p=2}^\infty \int_p^{p+1} p^{-7/6} \,dx \\[8pt]
\le {} & 1+ \sum_{p=2}^\infty \int_p^{p+1} (x-1)^{-7/6}  \, dx = 1 + \int_2^\infty (x-1)^{-7/6} \, dx \\[8pt]
= {} & 1 + \int_1^\infty x^{-7/6} \, dx =7.
\end{align}
So the sum is between $6$ and $7.$

Comment: If we assume one of A,B,C,D is correct, the the opposite direction is not needed, as only one interval features numbers $>6.$